# Hibernate Criteria - Novice Question II

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

What is the best way to add some sql to the select part of a Criteria object?

(I want to add SELECT myFunction AS distance so that I can later order by distance)

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

```
 List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
     .createAlias("kittens", "kit")
     .add( Restrictions.like("kit.name", "Iz%") )
     .list();
```

However I would advise you not to mix Hibernate criteria API with SQL code: choose to use either SQL (or better HQL) code or the criteria API.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried it out today, however (unless I am doing it wrong which is likely!) when you use the .createAlias("kittens","kit") the hbm.xml file has to have a reference to "kittens" otherwise it throws an error.  What I am looking to do is the equivalent of createAlias("SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( {alias}.latitude - " + point[1] ) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * ( "+point[0]" - {alias}.longitude ) * COS( {alias}.latitude  57.3 ) , 2 ) )" , "distance") So that I can later do .orderBy("distance")

Answer (score 1):

From Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html):

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
.setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
    .add( Projections.rowCount(), "catCountByColor" )
    .add( Projections.avg("weight"), "avgWeight" )
    .add( Projections.max("weight"), "maxWeight" )
    .add( Projections.groupProperty("color"), "color" )
)
.addOrder( Order.desc("catCountByColor") )
.addOrder( Order.desc("avgWeight") )
.list();
```

Comment: I am currently trying to work out how to implement this as a solution, currently to no avail, the difficulty I am finding in general is getting the sql function into hibernate in a meaningful way. The precise function I am trying to use is :-

SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( {alias}.latitude -  51.3814282 ) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * (   -2.3574537 - {alias}.longitude ) * COS( {alias}.latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) )  

where {alias} is a criteria rooted thus :- criteria.createCriteria("location.address");